# Cannot pull image from aws ecr

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

I'm tying to create a helm chart which is deploying image from aws ecr. Full code: https://github.com/rcbandit111/test_helm_chart

Every time I get error into Kubernetes when I install the helm chart:

```
Failed to pull image "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway:0.0.1": failed to pull and unpack image "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway:0.0.1": failed to resolve reference "123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/test-gateway:0.0.1": unexpected status from HEAD request to https://123456789.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/test-gateway/manifests/0.0.1: 401 Unauthorized
```

As you can see I have a job which is refreshing the credentials from aws ecr. Should I keep this job or use another approach to access the registry? How I can property configure the helm chart?

Comment: Based on your build script, those local JAR files should be placed under `service-project\libs`. At the very least, they should not be under `src\main\resources`, as the libraries are not "resources".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message you're encountering, "**401 Unauthorized**," indicates that the authentication to your AWS ECR (Elastic Container Registry) is failing. The job you have in your Helm chart to refresh the credentials is a good approach, but there might be some misconfiguration or timing issues.

1. Try to manually check ECR authentication (all relevant commands) from your local machine. Make sure IAM, region, token etc. are correct.
2. Timing issue. Have you tried ensuring that certain resources run in the correct order? Consider organizing the internal logic and utilizing Helm hooks to initiate actions at specific stages within the Helm chart's lifecycle. These stages include events like pre-install or post-delete of resources. Helm hooks enable you to perform tasks such as executing Jobs, creating ConfigMaps, or managing other Kubernetes objects as integral parts of the Helm deployment process

In Helm, there are two ways to use hooks for managing Kubernetes resources: Helm Hook Annotations and Helm Hook Manifests. These approaches serve similar purposes but have some key differences:

`Helm Hook Annotations`:

Annotations: Helm Hook Annotations are added as annotations to individual Kubernetes resources within the Helm chart's templates. You specify the type of hook (e.g., pre-install, post-install, pre-upgrade, or post-upgrade) directly in the resource's metadata.

Pros:

Simple: Annotations are easy to add to existing resource definitions.

Granular Control: You can apply hooks to specific resources within your chart.
Cons -

Tight Coupling: The hook information is tightly coupled with individual resources, making it less centralized and harder to manage as the number of resources grows.

Less Visibility: It can be challenging to get an overview of all hooks used in a chart.
Example:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
  name: my-deployment
```

`Helm Hook Manifests`:

Manifests: Helm Hook Manifests are YAML files that define Kubernetes resources specifically for hooks. These resources are separate from the main chart templates and are typically stored in a templates/hooks directory within the Helm chart.

Pros:

Centralized: Hook manifests provide a centralized place to define hooks, making them easier to manage and maintain.
Separation of Concerns: Hook manifests separate hook-related resources from the main chart templates, making the main templates cleaner and more focused.
Cons -
Requires Extra Files: You need to create separate YAML files for hook manifests, which can increase the number of files in your chart.

Example:

Hook manifest file templates/hooks/pre-install-job.yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pre-install-job
# ... job configuration ...
```

In your main chart templates, you can reference the hook manifest:

```
{{- include "mychart.hooks.pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}
```

Let's see what happens!

Reference:
https://helm.sh/docs/topics/charts_hooks/

##########################################
##########################################

Here is **a simple example** (annotation with weight)to control the execution order.

```
my-chart/
  ├── Chart.yaml
  ├── templates/
  │   ├── hooks/
  │   │   ├── pre-install-hook.yaml
  │   ├── deployment.yaml
  └── values.yaml
```

Contents of Chart.yaml:

```
apiVersion: v2
name: my-chart
description: A Helm chart to demonstrate hook execution order
version: 0.1.0
```

Contents of templates/hooks/pre-install-hook.yaml:

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: pre-install-job
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "1"
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: pre-install-container
          image: your-pre-install-image:tag
          # Add other container settings as needed
      restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Contents of templates/deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "5"
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app-container
          image: your-app-image:tag
          # Add other container settings as needed
```

Contents of values.yaml:

```
# Custom values for your Helm chart
```

1. pre-install-hook.yaml defines a pre-installation hook (a Job) with a weight of 1. This hook will execute before the main deployment.
2. deployment.yaml defines a Deployment with a weight of 5. This is the main application resource.
3. When you install or upgrade the Helm release, Helm will execute the pre-install-job with a weight of 1 before deploying the my-app Deployment with a weight of 5.

**Helm Hook Manifests** Example:

Assuming you have defined a custom pre-installation job template named `"my-custom-pre-install-job"`, here's an example of how to include it within a Deployment template:

templates/my-custom-pre-install-job.yaml

```
# templates/my-custom-pre-install-job.yaml

apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: my-custom-pre-install-job
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      name: my-custom-pre-install-job
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: job-container
          image: your-job-image:tag
          command: ["sh", "-c"]
          args:
            - |
              # Delete the existing secret if it exists (ignore errors if not found)
              kubectl delete secret my-secret-name --ignore-not-found=true
              
              # Create a new secret
              kubectl create secret generic my-secret-name \
                --from-literal=secret-key1=secret-value1 \
                --from-literal=secret-key2=secret-value2
          # Add other container settings as needed
      restartPolicy: Never
```

Contents of templates/deployment.yaml:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: my-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: my-app
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: my-app-container
          image: your-app-image:tag
          # Add other container settings as needed
---
{{- include "my-custom-pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}
```

In this example:

`"my-custom-pre-install-job"` is the name of your custom pre-installation job template, and you would replace it with the actual name you've given to your template.

The `{{- include ... }}` syntax is used to include and render your custom pre-installation job template with an indentation of 4 spaces within the Deployment template.

This way, when you install or upgrade your Helm chart, Helm will process the templates, and your custom pre-installation job defined in "my-custom-pre-install-job" will be included and executed before deploying the main my-app Deployment.

'Include' function reference:
https://helm.sh/docs/howto/charts_tips_and_tricks/#using-the-include-function

**Multiple Charts Solution**:
You can create a reusable subchart for managing Kubernetes secrets.

Here is a detailed example for two separate main Helm charts, "app-chart-1" and "app-chart-2," each using the "secrets-subchart" subchart to manage secrets.

Step 1: Create the Helm Subchart

```
secrets-subchart/
├── charts/
├── templates/
│   └── my-custom-pre-install-job.yaml
├── values.yaml
└── Chart.yaml
```

Step 2: Create Main Helm Chart 1 ("app-chart-1")

```
app-chart-1/
├── charts/
├── templates/
│   └── deployment.yaml
├── values.yaml
└── Chart.yaml
```

```
# app-chart-1/requirements.yaml
dependencies:
  - name: secrets-subchart
    version: 0.1.0  # Adjust the version as needed
    repository: "file://../secrets-subchart"  # Relative path to your subchart
```

```
# app-chart-1/values.yaml

secrets-subchart:
  secretData:
    secret-key1: custom-value1-app1
    secret-key2: custom-value2-app1
```

```
# app-chart-1/templates/deployment.yaml

---
{{- include "secrets-subchart.my-custom-pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}
```

Step 3: Create Main Helm Chart 2 ("app-chart-2")
The Same as above.

```
app-chart-2/
├── charts/
├── templates/
│   └── deployment.yaml
├── values.yaml
└── Chart.yaml

# app-chart-2/requirements.yaml
# app-chart-2/values.yaml
# app-chart-2/templates/deployment.yaml
---
{{- include "secrets-subchart.my-custom-pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}
```

This detailed example demonstrates how to create two separate Helm charts, "app-chart-1" and "app-chart-2," each using the same reusable subchart "secrets-subchart" to manage Kubernetes secrets. The secret data can be customized independently for each main chart by modifying the values.yaml files in each chart.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have a question. I have added into the github code wexample hook file but it's not clear where I need to add also `{{- include "mychart.hooks.pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}` Can you guide me?

Comment: Here is the reference. If you still have any questions, feel free to ask here.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63196657/helm-how-do-we-decide-indent-value-in-helm-templates

Comment: I also added two examples in my answer. Hope it is clear now.

Comment: I have additional questions: I added `Helm Hook Manifests Example` into the github repository. 1. Where into the job hook I need to add commands for deleting and creating kubernetes secret? 2. I have 20 helm charts. For sure I can't have 2 jobs to run aws ecr refresh? Maybe I need to have one main helm template which will hold the job? By the way if it's easy for you you can create a pull request directly to apply changes into the example repo?

Comment: Regarding the question one, please see the modified templates/my-custom-pre-install-job.yaml within the answer I edited. In terms of question 2, there is no limited number of jobs; it is related to your requirements. The reason you use a Helm hook is to ensure the execution order as per your requirements to resolve the timing issue.

Comment: Thanks but I will have 20 jobs which will do the same.

Comment: You can create a generic job using the Helm hook template as I shared above and '{{-include}}' it wherever you need.

Comment: I added "Multiple Charts Solution" into the answer. Hope you can solve this issue now.

Comment: I get error `Error: template: test-gateway/templates/deployment.yaml:68:4: executing "test-gateway/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "aws-secret-pre-install-job" .>: error calling include: template: no template "aws-secret-pre-install-job" associated with template "gotpl"`

Comment: I added into github repository the code that I'm testing.

Comment: It is obvious that the path of "aws-secret-pre-install-job" is incorrect, for instance {{- include "xxxx.my-custom-pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}

Comment: I tried `{{- include "templates.aws-secret-pre-install-job" . | nindent 4 }}` But I get the same error? What should be the correct one?

Comment: If you sub chart , you may need to use xxxx.aws-secret-pre-install-job. But I have looked your chart. You configuration should be fine. May I ask where the template 'gotpl' is? What does it for?

Comment: In my case I don't have a sub chart. I don't have any template or configuration named `gotpl`

Comment: {{- include "chart-name.aws-secret-pre-install-job" . | indent 4 }}, xxx. means chart-name. not templates. Try to add your chart-name as {{- include "chart-name.aws-secret-pre-install-job" . | indent 4 }}. If it doesn't work, it would be related to gotpl template Engine Compatibility.

Comment: Again not found.

Comment: test-gateway/templates/deployment.yaml, but your code is test-gateway-chart/templates/deployment.yaml, I can only help you until here. You have to check the minor typo issue.

Comment: I tried several options. You can see the changes into github but again I get `Error: template: test-gateway/templates/deployment.yaml:68:4: executing "test-gateway/templates/deployment.yaml" at <include "test-gateway.aws-secret-pre-install-job" .>: error calling include: template: no template "test-gateway.aws-secret-pre-install-job" associated with template "gotpl"`

Comment: I have some progress. Now job is running. Hook annotations were missing. But now for some reason the pod is not created. Any idea why?

Comment: Good. You have a little progress! Well, I can't understand what happening based on words above. the pod? which pod? hook annotation missing? job? which job? Btw, I quickly reviewed the code you shared in the link above; helm.sh/hook should be double-quoted for proper syntax.

Comment: It seems that the original question has long been answered and you're asking additional unrelated ones here. Please accept the answer and open new questions.